# Pass value from one controller to another

Tags: node.js

I have two controllers. One is login.js and the another one is home.js. I want to redirect to home controller from login controller with a value. To redirect to home controller, i wrote,

```
response.redirect('/home');
```

But, i cannot pass value here. When rendering a view with a value,

```
data = {'value':'hello'};    
response.render('view_login',data);
```

I want to do the same thing. I can pass value while rendering to the view but not when changing controller. Can i do this?

```
response.redirect('/home',{data: data});
```

Comment: please post some more code.

Comment: response.render works 100% ... but my problem is can i do  response.redirect('/home',{data: data});  ??

Comment: Node doesn't have a `response.render` method. So we don't know what you're actually trying to accomplish, in what library/framework... I mean, we could assume Express or Koa, but that's not a guarantee.

Comment: i just want to send a value while redirecting to a controller. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can use query parameters for this.
When you are redirecting your home page or any other controller then you can write like this

```
res.redirect(/<some controller>?data=<some data>)
```

and in that controller where you want to use this value..you can write like this

```
function login(req,res){
   var data = req.query.data;
}
```